# Adding hotspots with identical lat/long

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm adding hotspots to my map with the following code:

```
public void addMarker(MyCustomMarker marker) {

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(marker.getLatitude(), marker.getLongitude());

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));

}
```

What are the consequences of adding multiple hotspots with the identical lat/long? Will they both remain on the map and in memory, or will adding a new marker override the last one at that position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new marker with identical lat/long will make **both** remain on the map and in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The lat/long of a marker are just instance variables so no, this won't replace the existing Marker.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MD I'm not sure I understand.  The question can be answered with a yes/no and I explained why the answer is no.  Is this a problem with my answer or the question?